# Best way to return a function value and call another method after async animation block or timer has ended

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm currently developing an iPad book-style app, where I'm using a view controller to manage the main window, and then I use a number of page controllers equal to the number of pages in the book. All the page controllers inherit from a base class, PageController, where I defined the main methods used in every page, as well as the variables.

So, my view controller tracks the current page using an object of PageController type, and when I want to load another page, the view controller calls a method (transitionToNextPage), and this method returns the next page controller.

For example, if the current page is number 2, its class is Page02Controller, and the next page class is Page03Controller, which is returned from the Page02Controller.

The issue I've been fighting with, and to which I'm asking for some advice, is when I need to call the `transitionToNextPage` method, and the method returns when it's still doing some actions, like animating the transition (loading some frames, for example). For example, in the code below, I call the method `transitionToNextPage` and I start a timer to load some frames. However, the function returns right after the timer starts, and it counts for about 1 second.

```
- (PageController *)transitionToNextPage{
    if ([self.timerAnimationAngel isValid]) {
        [self.timerAnimationAngel invalidate];
        self.timerAnimationAngel = nil;
    }

    if ([self.timerAnimationFeather isValid]) {
        [self.timerAnimationFeather invalidate];
        self.timerAnimationFeather = nil;
    }

    [super hideTransitionButtons];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.f/(float)self.filenamesImagesTransition.count target:self selector:@selector(updateTransitionViews:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    self.imageViewTransition = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithMainBundle:self.filenamesImagesTransition[0]]]];
    self.imageViewTransition.layer.zPosition = kZPositionTransition;
    [self.mainView addSubview:self.imageViewTransition];

    return [[Page02Controller alloc] initPageNumber:2 withView:self.mainView withViewController:self.mainController];
}
```

So far, I have all the code working as I intend, but I don't think I'm doing in the best way. What I'm doing is calling a method from the super class of page controller when the timer ends, as shown in the code below:

```
- (void)updateTransitionViews:(NSTimer *)timer{
    static int indexImageTransition  = 0;

    if (indexImageTransition >= self.filenamesImagesTransition.count) {
        [super clearAllViewsIncludeBackground:YES];
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
        [super loadNextPage];
    }
    else{
        self.imageViewTransition.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithMainBundle:self.filenamesImagesTransition[indexImageTransition]]];
        indexImageTransition++;
    }
}
```

And the `[super loadNextPage]` calls a method in the view controller, and is defined in PageController (the super class) as:

```
- (void)loadNextPage{
    SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"loadNextPage");

    if([self.mainController respondsToSelector:selector]){
        #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
        [self.mainController performSelector:selector];
        #pragma clang diagnostic warning "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Selector not found.");
    }
}
```

The method `transitionToNextPage` is called from the view controller the following way:

```
- (IBAction)buttonNextPage:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Next page button pressed.");

    self.currentPage = [self.currentPage transitionToNextPage];    
    self.pageNumber = self.currentPage.pageNumber;
}
```

And finally, the method `loadNextPage` called from the PageController is defined in the view controller as:

```
- (void)loadNextPage{
    [self.currentPage loadPage];
}
```

The `loadPage` is now called from the next page, because it was already set before in `self.currentPage = [self.currentPage transitionToNextPage];`.
Here I lose the reference to the previous page, but it's not yet dealloc'ed because it still has a timer running, so I'm not having any issues doing this.

In the long term, and for future reusability, maybe the code is a bit confusing, but this way I can call the methods in the correct order, only when the timer finishes.

Another way that I was doing before was using notifications. I was listening to a notification called "@loadNextPage" which was posted by the current page controller when the timer was done. That way, I wasn't calling 3 or 4 additional methods in order to load the next page, but was only calling one.

I think the main advantage I have when using notifications is that the code is much simpler, and I just need to post/listen to a notification and call a single method.

I already thought about using a delegate, but I don't think it can be applied here the way I'm doing the transitions between pages.

I constantly run tests and measure the performance about memory and processor usage, and so far it's doing great. I don't have any memory leaks, and the app runs smoothly both on an iPad 2 with iOS 8 (non-retina) and iPad 4 with iOS 7 (retina).

**EDIT:**

I'm going to call the next page controller from inside the animation block or timer, without passing any information to the view controller.

I was assuming that it would retain the pages and cause leaks or have bad memory management performance, but that's not true. :)

Comment: TL;DR - what you're asking is impossible in the mentioned context, but there are many other ways you can do it - set a delegate, pass on a code block, and I bet there are at least a few more ways to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timers and similar hacks are simply wrong here. So is blocking or polling as a way of waiting. This is the standard asynchronous pattern. Look at any of the many Cocoa asynchronous methods to see how to deal with it, such as `presentViewController:animated:completion:`. Instead of writing a method `transitionToNextPage`, you write a method `transitionToNextPageWithCompletion:`. It takes a block parameter. When everything is over, the method calls the block, thus calling back into your code.

Comment: And here's an example of me doing it: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/iOS7bookExamples/bk2ch24p842downloader/ch37p1099downloader/MyDownloader.m This class has a method `download:completionHandler:`. In response, it performs a time-consuming download, and then calls back to the `completionHandler` (which it has carefully preserved in the meantime; you won't have to do that because everything will happen in one method).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and for the link you provided! I'm going to study your code and find the best solution to my project.

Comment: Actually, because you're using a timer, everything will _not_ happen inside the same method. But you can solve that, and you should do so, by using `dispatch_after` instead. GCD is half the answer to your prayers here; the use of a callback block is the other half.